# What should a scheme file contain in ManageTilecache_management?

Tags: arcpy, kml, import, error-000735, tiling-scheme

I am trying to create a big google kml tiles by using several small mosaic. While doing that in a python command I am having problem with a "Import_scheme". Can anybody help me about this import_scheme file?

For following python command,

```
arcpy.ManageTileCache_management("H:\FV","RECREATE_ALL_TILES‌​",”"Visible", "H:\FV\MosaicData.gdb\FVImages", "IMPORT_SCHEME", " " , "#", "H:FV\Bound.shp", "#", "4224470", "1128.497176")
```

I am getting this error,

> File "", line 1, in  File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 15656, in
>   ManageTileCache raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000735: Import Tiling
>   Scheme: Value is required

Answer (score 1):

You have several paths that may be interpreted wrong. You should always  insert a r ([raw string literal](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)) before the path if you use single backslashes in path. You also have a ” sign Before "Visible" which should not be there:

Change:

```
arcpy.ManageTileCache_management("H:\FV","RECREATE_ALL_TILES‌​",”"Visible",...
```

to:

```
arcpy.ManageTileCache_management(r"H:\FV","RECREATE_ALL_TILES‌​","Visible",...
```

I also think it is better to include the parameter names. If you do it will be easier to get the syntax right and you dont have to use empty strings ("") for optional parameters, you can just leave them out:

```
arcpy.ManageTileCache_management(in_cache_location=r"H:\FV", manage_mode="RECREATE_ALL_TILES", in_cache_name="Visible", in_datasource=r"H:\FV\MosaicData.gdb\FVImages", tiling_scheme="IMPORT_SCHEME", import_tiling_scheme=r"C:\Path\to\existing\scheme\file",...
```

You also specify that you want to use a tiling scheme (with "IMPORT_SCHEME") but you leave out the next parameter which is the:

> Path to an existing scheme file (.xml) or imported from an existing
>   image service or map service.

If you want to create a tile caching scheme use tool [Generate Tile Cache Tiling Scheme](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/generate-tile-cache-tiling-scheme.htm):

> Creates a tiling scheme file based on the information from the source
>   dataset. The tiling scheme file will then be used in the Manage Tile
>   Cache tool when creating cache tiles.